# Can actions have return types?

Tags: smart-contract, action, api, return

I've been looking at most of the example contracts and every action seems to return void.  Does this mean that you can not have a return type for your actions?  Instead, would you have to send a different get command to access data from your contract, i.e. "cleos get ".

If I wanted to return some data after calling an action is there a procedure for doing so?

Thanks.

Comment: No, you can add print and query the transaction to get console output, or you can store your result in table and query

Answer (score 1):

No, there's not. If you want to read data you must use `cleos get table` for Smart Contracts tables data or `cleos get actions` to see all the actions and transactions history data. Remember that, inside your action, you can always read data from your contract tables, or even external contracts ones.

After you push a transaction you can use the get table/actions to query results. I think the problem here is that you might wait 500ms (max) if you really want to make sure to query correct data (you won't do that for a "Facebook Like" action, but if you need to confirm a user balance from a token transfer).

Comment: Is this strictly true of all contracts? If so, how does `cleos get currency balance` work?

Comment: @kkurian currency balance is stored in multi_index table. You can get same result by `cleos get table eosio.token ${username} accounts`.

Comment: Yes, indeed. :-)